# Is there a way to search through Organization Github Repos to look for AWS Access Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-api, repo

Is there a way to search through my company's repos to see where developers have used personal AWS access keys in their code?

Comment: You could use something like [gitleaks](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks).

Comment: GitHub also offers [secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning), but for non-public repos, it requires [GitHub Advanced Security](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/about-github-advanced-security).